# Pear - Cannot execute on Uninstalled MAMP

Tags: php, mamp, pear

May be this question is a little stupid. But I've tried to solved it for two hours and cannot find the solution.

Firstly, I'm a hobby and novice PHP developer. Last year, I installed **MAMP** and **Pear** on my mac.

Today, I uninstalled old **MAMP** (from last year) and reinstall new **MAMP**. Now, when I type `pear` command on terminal, the following error occurs:

```
/Users/naylin/pear/bin/pear: line 28: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php: No such file or directory
/Users/naylin/pear/bin/pear: line 28: exec: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

I know the error occurs because `php5.4.10/bin/php` no longer exist on my machine. Currently, I have `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.18/bin/php` according to my last updated **MAMP**. But I don't know how to properly solve this problem.

**Update**

As Stony suggested in his answer, I try to modify `.pearrc` file. This file is normally located under **~/.pearrc** directory. At the last line of this file, there is config definition like that `s:44:"/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php";`. I modified it to the correct path of Php executable. In my case, it's `s:44:"/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.18/bin/php";`.

But, the error still occurs unfortunately. I even restart my mac with the hope to refresh config settings. Still, the error.
(I described this because I assume someone may be able to solve the error with this way on his mac.)

**How do I solved the error**

After trying 2 days to solve this problem, I gave up and try to uninstall this **pear** from my machine. And I planned to **reinstall** **pear** with correct settings again. I used the following command to uninstall it.

```
$ sudo pear uninstall pear
```

But the problem is I **could not** even run this command. The same error occured again.

So, I tweaked it. The error occurs because of configured directory for **PHP executable file** is not found. Hence, I created this directory by hand (I mean GUI). In my case, it is `"/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php"`. So, I created `"/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/"` directory first. After that, I copied all the files and folders from `"/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.18/"`.

After that, the error disappear and `pear` command works gracefully again. Then you can modify **Config Settings** of pear as suggested in Stony's answer (for correct PHP executable file). After you modify your settings, delete the tweaked folder that you created earlier (`"/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/"`).

(In my case, I uninstalled this pear. And I use the pear already included from MAMP php5.5.18.)

I'm not sure whether this is the correct way. But I hope anyone who experience this problem like me can solve the error if they don't found any more correct solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You set everywhere in your PEAR configuration the path to your PHP executable. You have to find that file and change the path to the new one.

You can use a command to change the value:

```
pear config-get php_dir
```

Then it should work. To show your configuration your can use:

```
pear config-show
```

And the configuration file is the `.pearrc` which should be somewhere in your user directory.

https://pear.php.net/manual/de/guide.users.commandline.config.php

Comment: I cannot even run 'pear config-show' or 'pear config-get'. The error in my question repeatedly occur. So I try to modify .pearrc file. This file is located under my user directory ~/.pearrc. I modify into this file from s:44:"/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php" to s:44:"/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.18/bin/php"; . But the error still occurs. Please, give me some suggestions. Thz.

Comment: Oh yes you're right :D pear is using the php executable :D sorry... but if you have changed that config it should work. Be sure that the path is really correct. And reopen your terminal if the file is cached or something else.